# Jquery find a row in unselected datatable by value in td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

Is there an efficient jQuery way in a "legacy" datatable to find a td containing my search value and then crawl up to the row tr?

I can use `$('#modalTable tbody').dataTable()[0].rows` to get all rows and then loop through all rows but would prefer a more efficient method if there is one.

Here is a screen capture of what I have tried based on information I found on similar questions:

[image]

I've expanded all the values in the Watches.  This screen capture is amazingly small!  You may need to save the image to see it better.

One thing that may be important is that this table is created in a popup.  I want to find the rows while the popup is opening but the data is already loaded into the table.  Here is the code:

```
//  Intitializes the select building table with new data
//  and resets the DOM every time the "Add" button is clicked.
initSelectableBuildingTable = function () {
    //If table exists destroy and reinitialize
    var is_table = isDataTable(jQueryVar.jSelectableBuildingTable)
    if (is_table) {
        resetDatatable(jQueryVar.jSelectableBuildingTable);
    }

    jQueryVar.jSelectableBuildingTable.dataTable({
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "aoColumns": [
            {
                "mDataProp": "Id", "bSortable": false, "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                    var sHtml = '<input type="button" class="button small addSelectedBuilding" value="Add" data-id="' + row.AssetId + '"/>'
                    return sHtml;

                },
                "bUseRendered": false,
                "sDefaultContent": ""
            },
            { "mDataProp": "AssetName", "bSortable": true },
            { "mDataProp": "SqFoot", "bSortable": true },
            { "mDataProp": "Uid", "bSortable": true },
            { "mDataProp": "Category", "bSortable": true },
            { "mDataProp": "Location", "bSortable": true }
        ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "mDataProp": null, "sDefaultContent": " ", "aTargets": [-1] }
        ],
        "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"><"clear">',
        "oLanguage": {
            "sEmptyTable": "No Meters found."
        },
        "sAjaxSource": $.baseURL("api/service/getassetsbyids"),
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            var ids = stateMap.selectedSiteIds.toString();
            var oData = { "ids": ids, "type": stateMap.selectedAssetType.toLowerCase() };
            $.ajax({
                url: sSource, // Do not add the base to this.  It should already be present
                type: "GET",
                data: oData,
                dataType: "json",
                success: fnCallback,
                complete: function () {
                    if (Info.model.getItemCount() > 0) {
                        disableAddButtonForSelectedItems();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Maybe there is some awesome cool thing that will allow me to find the the dt value and crawl up to the row.

Comment: Add a jsfiddle with the datatables

Comment: you could use the contains filter, but... it's just gonna do the inefficient thing you wanted to avoid behind the scenes anyway. Cant you just look through the data ti find an id or index you can select by rather than searching the dom?

Comment: So, what you're saying is "the only appropriate way to search the table is to loop through each row."  Yes?

Comment: Why the downvote?  I've tried everything I could find.  I've been working all day on this.  Many answers out there but nothing that works for me.  :-(

Comment: @Patricia people downvote without explanations, you can see it in my answer as well... :(

Comment: @Dekel - I did!  Some un-named not so nice person downvoted your answer and canceled my vote :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `:contains` selector in jquery:

```js
$('td:contains(Another option)').parent('tr').css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This is my text</td>
    <td>Some other text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Another option</td>
    <td>This is what I'm looking for</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>And some row</td>
    <td>Note this Another option row</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> **But** Note as in my example, it's not an exact match. It's "contains" match.

If you want to change it to exact match you can use something like that:

```js
var content_to_search = 'Another option'
$(`td:contains(${content_to_search})`).each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == content_to_search) {
    $(this).parent('tr').css('background', 'red');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This is my text</td>
    <td>Some other text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Another option</td>
    <td>This is what I'm looking for</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>And some row</td>
    <td>Note this Another option row</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: *"I can use `$('#modalTable tbody').dataTable()[0].rows` to **get all rows and then loop through all rows** but would prefer a more efficient method if there is one."* this loops through all the cells, so it's no more efficient is it?

Comment: I'm not sure how the `:contains` is implemented in jquery, but if (for example) it was using xpath (which available in some of the modern browsers) I'm not sure it was required.

Comment: That line gets me an array of rows (which, YES, contains all columns for each row.  Other answers use tablename tr in jQuery to find a value.  I've not been able to figure out how to get the results I want.  My attempts are in the screen capture, which you can see better if you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I was close.  You can click on the image to see just how close.  Technically, Dekel's answer is the correct answer, so I'm going to give the points to that answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45827242/1735836).  But I'm posting this answer just-in-case someone else finds themselves as confused as I was.

**I was trying to get the row and then perform whatever action I wanted on it** (WRONG!), which may still be possible but I found the better way that I was looking for.

This is the code that does what I wanted:

```
var ids = [];  // These will come from user selection 
ids.forEach(function (id)
    jQueryVar.jBuildingTable.find('tr input[data-id="' + id + '"]')  // Find row
    .prop("disabled", true).addClass('secondary');                   // perform action
```

Happy coding!